# Dynamic value to template slot name

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this component :

```
<tabs :items="tabs" v-model="tab" with-content @switch="switchTab">
    <template #tab(activeTab) >
      <div class="list" v-if="loaded">
        ...
      </div>
    </template>
</tabs>
export default {
name: "ProjectTranslations",
data: (vm) => ({
  tabs: [],
  activeTab: null,
  currentPage: 1,
}),
mounted() {
  this.tabs.push({id: this.user.language.id, title: this.user.language.name})
  this.tabs.push({id: 2, title: 'French'})
  this.activeTab = this.user.language.id;

},
async created() {
  await this.show();
},
computed: {
  tab: {
    get() { return this.activeTab; },
    set(tab) {
      this.activeTab = tab;
    },
  },
},
.......
```

The problem is that I can't set like this `#tab(activeTab)`. If I set `#tab(1)` is working, but I can't set it dynamically. Have you an idea how I can solve that ?

Comment: [Dynamic Slot Names](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Dynamic-Slot-Names)

Comment: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/vue-components-dynamic-slot-names-and-shorthands-efbace3990f1